# Como Hacer un filtro de una lista con SPINNER

Tags: android

Tengo una pregunta ...

Quería saber si es posible de hacer un filtro de una lista dinámica con `spinner` , se que se puede con un `EditText` pero no se si se puede con `Spinner`... o no se como hacerlo.

Mi código :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resultado);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTipoResp);
        String[] valores = {"Tipo de Repuestos.....","Accesorios","Rotulo","Amortiguadores","Bujes"};
        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, valores));
        ArrayList<DataLista> articulos=new ArrayList<>();
         data = new DataLista();

        data.setDescripcion("ROTULA SUP DODGE RAM 4X4 03/09");
        data.setId("VIE503182");
        data.setMarca("FORD");
        data.setRepuesto("Rotula");
        data.setmImage(R.drawable.todo);
        articulos.add(data);

        data = new DataLista();
        data.setDescripcion("BARRA CENTRAL FIAT 600 60/63");
        data.setId("VIE503182");
        data.setMarca("FIAT");
        data.setRepuesto("Accesorios");
        data.setImage(R.drawable.todo);
        articulos.add(data);


        data = new DataLista();
        data.setDescripcion("ROTULA SUP DODGE RAM 4X4 03/09");
        data.setId("VIE503182");
        data.setMarca("FORD");
        data.setRepuesto("Rotula");
        data.setImage(R.drawable.todo);
        articulos.add(data);

        data = new DataLista();
        data.setDescripcion("BARRA CENTRAL FIAT 600 60/63");
        data.setId("VIE503182");
        data.setMarca("FIAT");
        data.setRepuesto("Accesorios");
        data.setmImage(R.drawable.todo);
        articulos.add(data); 
    adapter = new Adaptergeneric(Resultado.this,articulos);

        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_eligida);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                String eligido = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);

               // Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(),eligido, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Supongo aca deberia hacer el filtro  y traer el nuevo resultado de la lista

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {
                // vacio

            }
        });
```

Comment: A que te refieres con un filtro? especifica lo que deseas.

Comment: Supongo que tengo una lista de productos en una lista , varios de esos productos son de la misma marca...con un spinner queríahacer un filtro para que me aparezca solo los productos de la misma marca  segun la seleccion ...Muchas gracias @Jorgesys por su ayuda

Comment: En una lista das clic a una marca y en el Spinner solo se muestran productos de la marca?

Comment: nooo el contrario , en el spinner doy click de una marca , y me recarga la lista , solo con los productos de dicha marca...

Comment: Quieres tener dos spinner ? uno donde selecciona la marca y al seleccionar dicha marca en el segundo spinner automáticamente aparezcan solo productos de la marca ? entiendo bien ?

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede amigo, ya te explico como hacerlo. Lo que debes hacer primero es rearmar un nuevo arreglo de strings que solo tenga aquellos con la categoria que deseas. Posteriormente debes notificar el adapter que hay una nueva fuente de information. Por como tienes tu codigo creo que la formas mas simple de hacerlo es crear un nuevo adapter y agregarlo a tu lista de la siguiente manera.

```
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTipoResp);
    String[] valores = {"Tipo de Repuestos.....","Accesorios","Rotulo","Amortiguadores","Bujes"};
    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, valores));
    ArrayList<DataLista> articulos=new ArrayList<>();
     data = new DataLista();

    data.setDescripcion("ROTULA SUP DODGE RAM 4X4 03/09");
    data.setId("VIE503182");
    data.setMarca("FORD");
    data.setRepuesto("Rotula");
    data.setmImage(R.drawable.todo);
    articulos.add(data);

    data = new DataLista();
    data.setDescripcion("BARRA CENTRAL FIAT 600 60/63");
    data.setId("VIE503182");
    data.setMarca("FIAT");
    data.setRepuesto("Accesorios");
    data.setImage(R.drawable.todo);
    articulos.add(data);


    data = new DataLista();
    data.setDescripcion("ROTULA SUP DODGE RAM 4X4 03/09");
    data.setId("VIE503182");
    data.setMarca("FORD");
    data.setRepuesto("Rotula");
    data.setImage(R.drawable.todo);
    articulos.add(data);

    data = new DataLista();
    data.setDescripcion("BARRA CENTRAL FIAT 600 60/63");
    data.setId("VIE503182");
    data.setMarca("FIAT");
    data.setRepuesto("Accesorios");
    data.setmImage(R.drawable.todo);
    articulos.add(data); 
adapter = new Adaptergeneric(Resultado.this,articulos);

    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_eligida);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            String eligido = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            for(DataLista articulo : articulos){
                ArrayList<DataLista> informacionFiltrada = new ArrayList<>();
                if (articulo.getRepuesto().equals(eligido){
                    informacionFiltrada.add(articulo)
                }
                adapter = new Adaptergeneric(Resultado.this,informacionFiltrada);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
           // Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(),eligido, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//Supongo aca deberia hacer el filtro  y traer el nuevo resultado de la lista

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {
            // vacio

        }
    });
```

Eso deberia hacer el truco. Espero sea de utilidad y mucha suerte